# Mouse scroll fast forward and increase volume in the same time in VLC

Tags: shortcut-keys, vlc

I encounter a weird issue with recent VLC version and I am not able to find information about this problem.

When I scroll using the mouse wheel during a video, it increase the volume *and* in the same time it fast forward the video (reciprocally decrease and rewind). It is pretty annoying.

Before < some update > the scroll simply decreased and increased volume.

When I go in **Preferences** >  **Hotkeys** there no mention of mouse wheel.

I am probably missing something obvious but anyone know where I can find the option to correct this problem ?

[image: vlc hotkeys screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my touchpad configuration.
Using a different configuration file fixed the problem.

Comment: what kind of configuration is it?